# How much can a PWA store?

Tags: web-applications, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

I asked myself how much can a PWA store offline ... I found out that it depends on the browsers.

- Chrome can store 33% of the free disk space available
- firefox 50% of free space available
- safari can store unlimited and on mobile safari can store 50MB.

But I found different numbers everywhere... **Can someone tell me the current numbers and are these for each PWA or the total browser caching storage?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would consider [Google developers article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa) as reliable source about browsers differences:

[image]

And this [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) to learn the difference between the Global and Domain limit:

[image]

> The **global limit** is calculated as 50% of free disk space.
>
> The **group limit** — this is defined as 20% of the global limit, but it has a minimum of 10 MB and a maximum of 2 GB. Each origin is part of a group (group of origins).

If you want to learn more about PWAs [I wrote a series of articles about this technology](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f) (covering also different offline caching strategies).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are these numbers for each PWA or the total browser storage?

Comment: If you have two different PWAs (typically using different domain) they will use each a group storage limit/quota. However the global limit is per browser and interests all your cached applications.

Comment: what about mobiles and their quotas?

Comment: These values are the same for mobile or desktop as the CACHE API uses these limits and they are related to the used browser.